# Cube rotation issue in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to rotate the cube when the user is touching it. To rotate it,is quite simple but actual problem is if the user is tilting it then always it should stop in particuler face(cube has 6 faces and i mean that only one face should be visible at one time). Please give your suggetion if anyone worked on that.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a cube this is simple: Face normals are the cartesian axes. So one looks straigt on a face if you constrain the rotations around the cartesian axes (X, Y, Z) and the rotation angles are multiple of pi/2 = 90°.

So in your code when the user stops interacting, set the rotation angles to the next multiple of 90°

```
fmod(round(angle/90) * 90, 360); // degrees
fmod(round(angle/(pi/2)) * pi/2, 2*pi); // radians
```

Either do it hard, or animate it.

If your object is not a cube, but arbitrary, you need to find the additional rotation for the face to get perpendicular to the view axis. This angle is determined by `acos( scalar_product(normalize(face_normal), normalize(view_axis)) )` the axis of rotation is given by  `cross_product(normalize(face_normal), normalize(view_axis))`